# Embed Dashboards Kibana with Security

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7, elasticsearch-opendistro, opensearch-security-plugin

I want to embed my dashboards made in Kibana in a webpage. However, I have security enabled in Elastic and Kibana, so to open a dashboard it requires the Kibana login.
There is any way I can auto-sign-in users to see Kibana dashboards in the webpage?
I already tried to POST the user credentials before doing a GET of the dashboard, and also tried to pass the credentials through the dashboard link but no success.

`Elasticsearch version : 7.4.2`